# What is the difference between reminiscence and nostalgia?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology, well-being, self, mood

Both reminiscence and nostalgia refer to thinking about the past, but where is the line between them?

I am looking into how reminiscence affects meaning in life and have found that most research focuses on nostalgia. I am trying to figure out what the difference is.
I thought that reminiscence refers to thinking about and recalling the past (for a variety of reasons), and that nostalgia is the feelings of longing that arise as a result of reminiscence. However I am struggling to find a distinction in the literature.

If anyone has a good definition/ can point me to where might clarify this I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you *with a useful answer* and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject. You said *"I am struggling to find a distinction in the literature"* and *"most research focuses on nostalgia"*. What research and literature have you read?  Can you please provide details?  Have you Googled "reminisce vs nostalgia" to see what comes up?

Comment: Yes, to add on to Chris's comment I think you need to demonstrate the use of these terms in the literature and the reasoning for them being used differently. Otherwise, you only need a dictionary, and this site isn't an appropriate substitute for a dictionary.